# How to call a function using Apply with Optional parameter naming?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apply, optional-parameters

Using this function def: `myFunc(p1, p2, p3 = 3, p4 = 4){ //do something }`

I understand that you can call a function using `Apply`, 
Like this: `myFunc.apply([1, 2])`

Where 1 is p1 and 2 is p2.

But how would one use `apply` when specifying a specific optional param name?:

`myFunc(1, 2, p4=>5)`

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have named parameters in the first place. `p4=>5` is an arrow function, short for `function(p4) { return 5; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript to pass specific named parameters you would need to pass an object. You can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get the desired result.

```
{p1: 1, p2: 2, p4: 5}
```

```js
function myFunc({p1, p2, p3 = 3, p4 = 4}){ console.log(p3); }


myFunc.apply(null, [{p1: 1, p2: 2, p4: 5}]);
```

Comment: If the person who cast a downvote could explain why I would appreciate it. I get the idea that they probably did so because it was a duplicate question, but I obviously wasn't aware or I wouldn't have answered. That doesn't make my answer less valid.

Comment: Yes! That's what I need.

Answer (score 4):

In the same way you would by calling it directly. When calling a function, to skip over a default parameter, you pass `undefined`:

```
myFunc(1, 2, undefined, 4);
```

You can do the same thing using `apply`, just pass in `undefined` when you want the default parameter to kick in:

```js
function myFunc(p1, p2, p3 = 3, p4 = 4) {
    console.log("p1:", p1);
    console.log("p2:", p2);
    console.log("p3:", p3);
    console.log("p4:", p4);
}

myFunc.apply(null, [11, 22, undefined, 44]);   // skips over p3
```

Comment: The same thing happened with my answer. I'm pretty positive it's just pettiness for unknowingly answering a dup question. *shrug*

Comment: @zfrisch Even fabio's answer and the question itself got a downvote. And the question is no longer marked as a duplicate because I've reopened it. The downvote happened afterwards, so I guess it's just a serial downvoter.

Comment: I like this for simplicity. But I'm going with sfrisch answer because it allows me to pass in only what I need to pass in and nothing more, ie, no undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have named arguments (ES6 included). So as you can guess, you can only use `apply` with positional arguments, so there's no way to use `apply` the way you want to.

In ES6, a way to kind of emulate named args is to use an object, for example:

```
myFunc({ from=3, to=5 });
```

Example with the technique above and apply (ES6):

```
let f = ({ p1='a', p2='b'} = {}) => { console.log(p1, p2); }
// logs 'a', 'b'
f.apply(this, [{ p1: 'c' }])
// logs 'c', 'b'
```

You can read more here: http://2ality.com/2011/11/keyword-parameters.html

Comment: Looks like you copied that example from http://2ality.com/2011/11/keyword-parameters.html and just changed the function name. You should probably add attribution.

Comment: I also ran into it while trying to make sure that his syntax didn't really exist, it was still on my screen while I read your answer. :)